# Protractor - touch simulating

Tags: javascript, protractor, touch

I have a component that activates if the browser is touch enabled.

What is the best way to mock touch enabled browser in protractor (similar to the device mode in chrome developer tools).

**Resolved:**

It seems chrome doesn't activate the touch when opened via protractor so in my protractor.conf.js file I did the following:

```js
exports.config = {
  multiCapabilities: [{
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        mobileEmulation: {
          deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 5'
        },
        args: [
          '--touch-events=enabled'
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know, how exactly the "is touch enabled" check is implemented in your case? Thanks.

Comment: from the swipe.js code it appears to be this line. where root is the global variable

('ontouchstart' in root) || root.DocumentTouch && _document instanceof DocumentTouch